# event hiding in inherited class not working

Tags: c#, events, inheritance

I'm trying to hide an event from an inherited class, but not via EditorBrowserable attribute.
I have a *DelayedFileSystemWatcher* which inherits from *FileSystemWatcher* and I need to hide the Changed, Created, Deleted and Renamed events and make them private.
I tried this, but it does not work:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Do not use
    /// </summary>
    private new event FileSystemEventHandler Changed;
```

The XML comment is not showing in IntelliSense (the original info is shown). However, if I change the access modifier to public, the XML comment is shown in IntelliSense.

Any help is is welcome.

Comment: doesn't it seem that Changed is something else as well... why not you change the event name and check?

Comment: Well, since -- if you declare the events `private` -- the original events seem to show up in IntelliSense anyway (judging from your comment that the original info is shown), declaring your new events `public` instead and at least get the proper IntelliSense info seems advantageous to declaring them `private`...?

Comment: It seems like this is a case where composition (has-a) would be better instead of inheritance (unless you need to pass instances of your class to functions which accept `FileSystemWatcher` as an argument)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use it but it trivially solves your problem:

```
class MyWatcher : FileSystemWatcher {
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    private new event FileSystemEventHandler Changed;
    // etc..
}
```

The only other thing you can do is encapsulate it.  Which is doable, the class just doesn't have that many members and you are eliminating several of them:

```
class MyWatcher : Component {
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    public MyWatcher() {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
        // etc..
    }
    public string Path {
        get { return watcher.Path; }
        set { watcher.Path = value; }
    }
    // etc..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you inherit it, you have to provide it.

Maybe instead of inheriting:

```
Public Class DelayedFileSystemWatcher : Component
{
  private FileSystemWatcher myFSW;

  public DelayedFileSystemWatcher
  {
    myFSW = new FileSystemWatcher();
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be my approach too. If you have a need to hide members from a base class, you simply shouldn't use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make something that's public in the base class into private in the derived class. If nothing else, it's possible to cast the derived class to the base class and use the public version.

The way you hide the base class's event actually works, but only from where the new event is visible, that is, from inside the derived class. From outside, the new event is not visible, so the base class's is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

The `new private` solution didn't work for me, calls are still routed to the base class.

What did work was making the event virtual at the base, overriding it at the derived and marking it as obsolete.

At the base

```
private event EventHandler _ItemSelected_Event;
public virtual event EventHandler ItemSelected_Event
{
  add => _ItemSelected_Event += value;
  remove => _ItemSelected_Event -= value;
}
```

At the derived:

```
#pragma warning disable CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
[Obsolete("Removed from interface, use SelectionChanged Instead", true)]
public override event EventHandler ItemSelected_Event
{
    add => _ = value;
    remove => _ = value;
}
#pragma warning restore CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
```

And if you force its usage:

[image]